$*\rightarrow BG=[*/G]$ is representable
I think this is a very fundamental question in stack theory, indeed, $BG=[*/G]$ is an algebraic stack and $*\rightarrow BG$ is its smooth atlas, but I am wondering whether there exists a direct and simple way to see that in the category of stacks, such pullback $X\times_{BG} *$ along the morphism $X\rightarrow BG$ is a scheme when  $X$ is a scheme. I believe there must be some textbook explaining this?
Remark: here we take the $BG=[*/G]$ as the colimit of the simplicial diagram $\triangle^{op}\rightarrow Stk: n\rightarrow \{G^{n}\}_{n}=G\times \cdots \times G$ corresponding to the $G$ action (that is, $G^{2}=G\times G\stackrel{d_{0}}{\longrightarrow} G:(g_{1},g_{2})\rightarrow (g_{1}g_{2})$ and $G^{2}=G\times G\stackrel{d_{1}=projection}{\longrightarrow} G:(g_{1},g_{2})\rightarrow g_{2}$).

This depends on how you define things. One strategy to define $[U/G]$ for $U$ an $S$-scheme and $G$ a smooth affine algebraic group scheme over $S$ is to specify the associated functor. For an $S$-scheme $T$ one defines $[U/G](T)$ to be the category of principal $G$-bundles $P\to T$ with a $G$-equivariant morphism (in the category of $S$-schemes) $P\to U$. Applying the 2-Yoneda lemma, one can prove that subject to this definition, $U\times_{[U/G]} T \to T$ is exactly the principal bundle classified by the morphism $T\to [U/G]$. In particular, $U\to [U/G]$ is representable.
To read a more coherent account of this, you could try Alper's notes on algebraic stacks (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/moduli.pdf) which I think are really great.
